# creating javascript library with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I don't understand why this is being so complicated I want my project to have 2 separate work spaces where one is a library that will be distributed and the other will be used for testing... this is how i have the file structure

```
project  
--engine
---math
----vec2.js
---dist  
----library.js  
---main.js  
--sandbox  
---main.js
```

I want to build the "engine" project with webpack and es6 modules so I get a "library" file that can be used in "sandbox".

The "engine" main file would look something like this

```
import vec2 from './math/vec2';
export default class Library {
   constructor() {
      this.vec2 = vec2;
   }
}
```

An then the sandbox main file would look something like this

```
import lib from '../engine/dist/library';
const game = new lib();
```

The problem is when I build the "library.js" file with webpack and import it in the "sandbox" main file I can't call any of the classes therein. I get this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: o.default is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (library.js:1)
    at e (library.js:1)
    at library.js:1
    at library.js:1
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: __dirname+"/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname+"/dist",
        filename: "library.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

I must be missing some configuration webpack needs or some plugin that will make this work. I simply want to build the library with webpack using es6 modules so it can be used in another project but I have no idea how to configure it. I'm using babel for transpilling es6 to es5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget). In this case the target `commonjs-module` is appropriate. So your `output` would be:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname+"/dist",
    filename: "library.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs-module"
},
```

The different targets are described in the docs. And you might also want to read [Guides - Authoring Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).

Comment: Man thank you so much... I been clueless about how this was gonna work, and thank you for the link.